# Bean property not updated on action

Tags: jsf, properties, managed-bean

I have the following Facelet page:

```
        <ui:define name="content">

            <h:form id="selectReport">

                <div>
                    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{reportsController.selectedReport}">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{reportsController.reportsList}"/>
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                </div>
                <div>

                    <h:commandButton value="Ir al reporte"
                                     action="#{reportsController.goToReport}"/>

                </div>
            </h:form>

            <h:form id="dateRangeSetupForm"
                    rendered="#{reportsController.showDateRangeSetupForm}">
                <div>
                    <h:outputLabel value="Desde:"/>
                    <h:inputText id="fromDate"
                                 value="#{reportsController.fromDate}"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h:outputLabel value="Hasta:"/>
                    <h:inputText id="toDate"
                                 value="#{reportsController.toDate}"/>
                </div>
            </h:form>

            <h:form id="billOfLadingSetupForm"
                    rendered="#{reportsController.showBillOfLadingSetupForm}">
                <div>
                    <h:outputLabel value="# Factura:"/>
                    <h:inputText id="invoiceNumber"
                                 value="#{reportsController.invoiceNumber}"/>
                </div>
            </h:form>


            <h:form id="submitForm">
                <h:commandButton id="processReport" value="Generar Reporte"
                                 action="#{reportsController.processReport}"/>
                <h:commandButton id="goBack" value="Regresar"
                                 action="mainMenu"/>
            </h:form>

        </ui:define>
```

In which I let the user select a report, and render a form to setup parameters depending on the report. The problem is that when I render for example the `billOfLadingSetupForm` and fill the `inputText`, then click on the `processReport` button the `invoiceNumber` property of my bean is not updated, it is set to `null`.

I have noticed that if I type `Return` after filling the `inputText` and then click the `processReport` button the property does get updated. This is strange I haven't face this problem before. Do you have any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever a form get submitted, then only the data inside that form will be sent. The data of the other forms won't be sent. That's by HTML specification. You need to put all inputs and buttons which belongs to each other inside the **same** `<h:form>`. Replace all your splitted `dateRangeSetupForm`, `billOfLadingSetupForm` and `submitForm` forms by `<h:panelGroup>` and put them all inside one and same `<h:form>`.

Something like this:

```
<ui:define name="content">
    <h:form>
        <div>
            <h:selectOneMenu value="#{reportsController.selectedReport}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{reportsController.reportsList}"/>
            </h:selectOneMenu>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h:commandButton value="Ir al reporte" action="#{reportsController.goToReport}"/>
        </div>
    </h:form>

    <h:form>
        <h:panelGroup id="dateRangeSetupForm" rendered="#{reportsController.showDateRangeSetupForm}">
            <div>
                <h:outputLabel value="Desde:"/>
                <h:inputText id="fromDate" value="#{reportsController.fromDate}"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h:outputLabel value="Hasta:"/>
                <h:inputText id="toDate" value="#{reportsController.toDate}"/>
            </div>
        </h:panelGroup>

        <h:panelGroup id="billOfLadingSetupForm" rendered="#{reportsController.showBillOfLadingSetupForm}">
            <div>
                <h:outputLabel value="# Factura:"/>
                <h:inputText id="invoiceNumber" value="#{reportsController.invoiceNumber}"/>
            </div>
        </h:panelGroup>

        <h:commandButton id="processReport" value="Generar Reporte" action="#{reportsController.processReport}"/>
        <h:commandButton id="goBack" value="Regresar" action="mainMenu"/>
    </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

Make sure that the bean is put in the view scope. Otherwise the conditions for the `rendered` attribute won't be preserved. See also [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked)

Comment: Thanks, it's working now. I guess my knowledge is even more limited than I thought =(